# How to use 'dogly' correctly

Tags: word-choice

Recently, as it is shown in previous questions, we learn how to use *asininely* and how to use *bovinely*. Now, along this line, I would like to learn how to use *dogly* properly.

In particular, I would like to know whether phrases like

> Our friends looked at us *dogly*.
>
> Our friends worked *dogly*.

are good English. Are they?

I know that there are better or more idiomatic words to replace 'dogly' there, but, thinking to the audience I have to talk to, I would prefer, if acceptable, to use 'dogly'.

Comment: If I really had to use it I'd use it as a modifier: *Our friends gave us a dogly look.*

Comment: If this were a course of lessons, you could say 'Recently we have learnt how to use *asininely*...' It is not, and many of us have known for some time how to use *asininely*: sparingly at most.

Comment: The OED has exactly _one_ quote for the adverb ‘dogly’, and it is from 1552. It’s not a word. As an adjective (like how @z7sgѪ used it), it is quite rarely used, but does exist. It is mostly literal then, meaning “of the nature of a dog, canine”, but also has the now obsolete meaning ‘cynical’ (the philosophers, not common cynicism)—which makes sense, of course, since ‘cynical’ just means ‘doglike’ to begin with.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the use of a non-existent word.

Comment: @Janus, I think TimLymington's comment applies everytime a word is reported in the Merriam-Webster, [as it is the case here](http://i.word.com/idictionary/dogly), but someone else affirms *asininely* that it is not word.

Comment: I cannot see their definition, since I am not subscribed to the unabridged Merriam-Webster. But when a (non-technical, non-latinate) word is put down as unknown by (so far) five erudite, linguistically minded native speakers, and the largest English dictionary in the world marks it as both obsolete and rare, I’d say it’s far more asinine to persist in using it simply because it is included in a dictionary.

Comment: Wiktionary has 3 quotations and in each case it is used in the manner of a cutesy made-up-word, always following the word *dog*.  "A dog doing its dogly duty." etc.

Comment: In standard English (and pretty much any variety of English), nouns do not produce adverbs with the '-ly' suffix. 'dogly' is not a well-formed English word.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what *your* standard of "good English" is, but *dogly* is not a word that *I* can imagine using, nor would I expect to hear it from any native English speaker.

The word *doggily*, on the other hand, is regularly formed from the adjective *doggy*, and I would not find it strange in this context, even though I'm not sure that I have ever heard it before.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly does this word 'dogly' mean? Presumably 'in the manner of a dog'? But what is that? I know what 'asinine' and 'bovine' mean when used metaphorically, but have no ideas about 'dogly', nor incidentally has the Oxford Dictionary of English. There is an excellent word 'doggedly' which I suspect derives from dog meaning 'showing tenacity and grim persistence'. That word would seem to me to own the rights to 'in the manner of a dog'.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're not thinking of *doggedly*?

Answer (score 1):

One can [work like a dog](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/work+like+a+dog)

> work like a dog/trojan:
>   to work very hard. He **worked like a dog** all day to finish the wallpapering.

One can look at someone with [puppy dog eyes](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=puppy%20dog%20eyes)

> enlarging your eyes over dramatically with a sad face to get whatever you desire (most of the time.)

One can be as [crooked as a dog's hind leg](http://www.metaphordogs.org/Dogs/entries/crooked.html)

> Dishonest, corrupt, evil.

One can even drink [Working Dog wine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_Dog_Winery)

But I highly doubt on can do anything **dogly**, except to ***love unconditionally***.

*However, as I love dogs, I look forward to trying to keep this open, and to the replies.

Answer (score 1):

> In particular, I would like to know whether phrases like "Our friends looked at us dogly" are good English. Are they?

Though they would likely be understood, they are certainly not anything that a native speaker of English would say.

Try **[doggishly](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/doggishly)** if you intend to mean "in the manner of a dog".